# Debugging instantiated classes in Magento

Tags: php, magento, attributes

In PHP there `get_object_vars`, `get_class` and methods that return information about the class, we can use the Magento `Zend_Debug::dump()`, `Mage::log()` and up `XDebug`, but during module development in Magento, where we need overwrite some part of the administrative panel, for that we must look for the correct classes.

How to get list of all instantiated classes accessing a page of Magento?

Example: `X` user accessed `Catalog->Attributes->Manage Attribute`, how to generate a Debug with the list of all classes that were instantiated when the user accessed the Manage Attribute?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "cheap" way of doing this would be to add a

```
<!-- 
<?php print_r( get_included_files() ); ?>
-->
```

to the end of `index.php`.  This would print out every file included by Magento for a particular request, and since Magento's files are named consistently you could derive the class names.

If you're interested in spending a little money, I develop and sell a commercial debugging extension for Magento called [Commerce Bug](http://commercebugdemo.pulsestorm.net).  This extension outputs a ton of useful debugging information for each page request.  The [demo page](http://commercebugdemo.pulsestorm.net) can give you a feel for how it works (as well as reveal information for Magento's stock theme).

Comment: THK, I found also the Mage_Core_Model_Config::getModelInstance